# Checking if objects exists and manually raising an error if it doesn't

Tags: python, django, error-handling

I need to check if an object exists in a table,if doesn't raise an error and save it to the django `cronjoblog` table automatically.

here's a code that partially does what I want, but it doesnt raise an error an save it to the cronjoblog table:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

some_object= Some_object.objects.filter(active=True)
try:
    some_object.get()
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    print("Either the entry or blog doesn't exist.")
```

I need something like:

```
some_object= Some_object.objects.filter(active=True)
if not some_object:
    raise ObjectDoesNotExist("Either the entry or blog doesn't exist.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify your existing code as follows.

```
try:
    some_object.get()
except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
    raise ObjectDoesNotExist("Either the entry or blog doesn't exist.") from e
```